# directory lookup for the file(Could not find the specific path)

Tags: sql

I have some problem in sql server. i am trying to create database from the MDF file but getting error directory lookup for the file .

```
CREATE DATABASE [Live] ON
( FILENAME = N'E:\MDF Files\MasterDataBase.mdf'),
( FILENAME = N'E:\MDF Files\MasterDataBase_log.ldf')
FOR ATTACH
GO
```

Comment: Are you sure this is the exact path? check again carefully? also, do you have admin privilege?

Comment: @Rahul....I am using Local server

Comment: This error comes mainly when the path mentioned is not correct (even for a small typo mistake)